# angular 2 losing data on page reload

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

I get a list of reservations from the NGRX/store like this, the data comes in properly but disappears when the page reloads. I have to change routes to get it back.

```
ngOnInit() {

this.store.select(state => state.authState.profile).subscribe(profile => {

  this.profile = profile;
  if (this.profile) {
    this.userId = this.profile.$key;
  }
    });
    if (this.userId) {
    this.reservations$ = this.reservationService.loadUserReservations(this.userId);
  }
 }

   ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.userId) {
    this.reservations$ = 
    this.reservationService.loadUserReservations(this.userId);
      }

  }
```

not sure if this is enough code to illustrate the problem.

in my auth service

```
this.auth$.authState.subscribe(user => {
  if (user) {

    const userData = user;
    const userRef = db.object("users/" + userData.uid);

    const dataToSet = {
      displayName: userData.providerData[0].displayName,
      email: userData.providerData[0].email,
      photoURL: userData.providerData[0].photoURL,
      providerId: userData.providerData[0].providerId,
      registeredAt: new Date()
    };

    userRef.take(1).subscribe((user) => {
      if (user.$exists()) {
        // console.log('user exists', user);
        this.store.dispatch(this.authActions.updateUserInfo(user));

      } else {
        // console.log('user does not exists');
        userRef.set(dataToSet)
          .then((result) => {
            // console.log(result)
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            // console.log(error);
          });
      }
    });
    // console.log('hello user', user);
    this.store.dispatch(this.authActions.loginSuccess(user));
  } else {
    this.store.dispatch(this.authActions.logOutUser());
  }
});

}
```

I'm using Firebase and subscribing to the authState changes. 
when the user log ins I dispatch an action to update the store, I'm only using the authState.profile to filter the user's reservations and all the works fine. I'm setting the observable reservations$ on ngOnInit().

Comment: by 'page reload' you mean whole page reload? like when you press browser F5?

Comment: yes, a full reload. the angular CLI reloads the pages when I save changes, that's how I noticed it.

Comment: ok. so you refresh page but stay at the same component (route). there seem to be several problems here. but first, could you please share code where you actually fill `authState` part of the state? and what triggers that code that fills that state? are you doing that on some login component or?

Comment: so, when user logs in you fill in profile data into authState but you don't save that anywhere into localStorage or some other persistance (cookie or something), right?

Comment: right, I have other pages with data from the store, that doesn't lose the data when the page refreshes. I'm not using local-storage anywhere on this app.

Answer (score 3):

There are several things to say here.

First of all, store is just a plain, in-memory, javascript object. That means that on page reload its gone.

Second, if you need any kind of persistance of user Auth data then you should, upon user logs in, put that data into store (what you already do) and additionally put it into some localStorage or cookie. Then you should have mechanism of reading the localStorage/cookie to get auth data and refill store on page reload (or any page load, for that matter). [This is a separate issue, just givin you context]

Now, one thing you probably never want ot happen is that user ends up on your reservations component if he is not logged in (in other words, if there are no authState data in store). And that is exactly what is happening.

You have several options to solve this. One, probably best, is to have AuthGuard that will run in CanActivate for the route that your reservation component uses.

So, something like this...

CheckAuthGuard:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.store.select(yourPartOfStateWhereAuthDataIs)
      .map(profileData => !!profileData)
      .take(1)
      .do(authenticated => {
        if (!authenticated) {
          this.router.navigate([ 'login' ], {
            queryParams: { referer: this.createUrl(route) }
          });
        }
      });
    }
```

and then in your routing, for reservations component route:

```
{
  path: '',
  component: ReservationsComponent,
  canActivate: [CheckAuthGuard]
}
```

this will ensure that:

1. if user ends up on reservations component > there is AuthData
2. if there is no AuthData in store, when attempting to go to reservations > user will get redirected to login page

Now, one additional thing about getting reservations. Seems like you are not getting reservations from store but from service directly. What i'd suggest is to actually put one more guard, for Reservations component and there do:

1. Load Reservations (through dispatching ngrx action which will in turn call service you already have)
2. When your store is filled with Registration data, then your guard will allow going to Reservations component
3. in your reservations component you would do `store.select(PartOfStoreWhereReservationsAre)` and use them from there

It might be a bit too many infos but i hope you'll find your way through it ;)

Comment: thank you for taking the time to help me, and writing a detailed response, I will try and implement this.

Comment: no problem, i am glad if it will help you in any way because i know exactly feeling where you are. i was there a few months ago ;). i would suggest, first implement guard, make user being redirected to login on page load. and go from there. after that implement reservations in store and store.select(reservations) in your component onInit(). ;) if you'll need more help just ping.